# Why is my API not getting loaded for my minecraft-Plugin?

Tags: java, api, plot, minecraft, bukkit

I made myself a fancy TikZ-Api which allows to make a visualisation of Data (Plotting, diagram). The way it works is, you make an instance of the API like
 `TikZAPI api = new TikZAPI();` and then you add your Data for the plot (simple plot with dots) like `api.addPoint(xCoord, yCoord)`. After I collected some data, I can print the entire code for the plot with `api.print();`. Then the code will appear in the console and I can copy and paste it manually into a LaTeX-Document where I can view the plot. Now the actual problem has nothing to do with the API, the API works perfectly fine. I want to collect some data of my minecraft server for example the maximum player count per hour and add this data to a plot to let it print into the console. BUT when I use my API as a library (IntelliJ: Project Structure -> Libraries -> + -> Library, which works fine, I can access all methods of my API in my plugin) and reload the server I get this error:

```
org.bukkit.command.CommandException: Unhandled exception executing command 'test' in plugin TestAPI v1.0.0
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:47) ~[Spi
got.jar:git-Spigot-ad703da-e2403a3]
        at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:14
9) ~[Spigot.jar:git-Spigot-ad703da-e2403a3]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R1.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServ
er.java:755) ~[Spigot.jar:git-Spigot-ad703da-e2403a3]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R1.PlayerConnection.handleCommand(PlayerCo
nnection.java:1703) ~[Spigot.jar:git-Spigot-ad703da-e2403a3]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R1.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.jav
a:1546) ~[Spigot.jar:git-Spigot-ad703da-e2403a3]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R1.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.jav
a:47) ~[Spigot.jar:git-Spigot-ad703da-e2403a3]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R1.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.jav
a:1) ~[Spigot.jar:git-Spigot-ad703da-e2403a3]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R1.PlayerConnectionUtils.lambda$0(PlayerCo
nnectionUtils.java:19) ~[Spigot.jar:git-Spigot-ad703da-e2403a3]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R1.TickTask.run(SourceFile:18) ~[Spigot.ja
r:git-Spigot-ad703da-e2403a3]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R1.IAsyncTaskHandler.executeTask(SourceFil
e:144) ~[Spigot.jar:git-Spigot-ad703da-e2403a3]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R1.IAsyncTaskHandlerReentrant.executeTask(
SourceFile:23) ~[Spigot.jar:git-Spigot-ad703da-e2403a3]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R1.IAsyncTaskHandler.executeNext(SourceFil
e:118) ~[Spigot.jar:git-Spigot-ad703da-e2403a3]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R1.MinecraftServer.aZ(MinecraftServer.java
:943) ~[Spigot.jar:git-Spigot-ad703da-e2403a3]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R1.MinecraftServer.executeNext(MinecraftSe
rver.java:936) ~[Spigot.jar:git-Spigot-ad703da-e2403a3]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R1.IAsyncTaskHandler.awaitTasks(SourceFile
:127) ~[Spigot.jar:git-Spigot-ad703da-e2403a3]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R1.MinecraftServer.sleepForTick(MinecraftS
erver.java:920) ~[Spigot.jar:git-Spigot-ad703da-e2403a3]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R1.MinecraftServer.v(MinecraftServer.java:
852) ~[Spigot.jar:git-Spigot-ad703da-e2403a3]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R1.MinecraftServer.lambda$0(MinecraftServe
r.java:164) ~[Spigot.jar:git-Spigot-ad703da-e2403a3]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_291]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: tikzapi/TikZAPI
        at test.Commands.onCommand(Commands.java:39) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:45) ~[Spi
got.jar:git-Spigot-ad703da-e2403a3]
        ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: tikzapi.TikZAPI
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.
java:167) ~[Spigot.jar:git-Spigot-ad703da-e2403a3]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.
java:96) ~[Spigot.jar:git-Spigot-ad703da-e2403a3]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
        at test.Commands.onCommand(Commands.java:39) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:45) ~[Spi
got.jar:git-Spigot-ad703da-e2403a3]
        ... 18 more
```

Well, I think the error is that the API is not getting loaded. But HOW can I do this? I already put the API into the plugins folder of my server, does not work. I made a subfolder in the plugins folder called "lib", did not work either. It does not matter if I use Eclipse or IntelliJ, both IDEs do not work. I have read that it has something to do with the manifest file but how do I make such an manifest file and does it really fix my problem? I cant use maven, because its my own API I made for myself and I want to use it like a normal library. Any ideas?

Comment: Seems like your API is not loaded. If you put your API alone in the plugins folder, do you get the log messages of it loading ? Have you added your API in your `plugin.yml` dependencies. What type of compiler do you use (Maven, Plain Manifest + IDE) ? Is you API an actual plugin  or just classes with utilities ? I may be able to help you with those information.

Comment: No, I just loaded the API like for example the bukkitlib library for being able to make a bukkit plugin via buildpath. I dont use maven and when I put my API inside my plugins folder, I will get an error that the API is not getting recognized as a plugin but that should be okay, because its not a plugin but all in all this did not work. I am really puzzeled and I did not add anything to my plugin.yml, which lines do I have to add?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your TikZ-Api is already compiled .jar file.

I will try to give you solution for IntelliJ IDEA, but general idea is same for all IDEs. When you add .jar into the libraries and then compile your plugin, IDE assumes that all these sources will be provided by VM instance during run and IDE does not have to pack the library sources with your plugin JAR file. This is true ONLY for `bukkit.jar` since bukkit starts first and then it loads plugins. It does not know that there is another API JAR somewhere which should be also loaded...

**First** simple solution is to copy raw (non-compiled) API .java sources into your plugin in the IDE and not add library at all. (Useful only if your API has few .java files and you still have them available)

**Second** solution is to add .jar API into libraries (as you mentioned) and tell the IDE that some libraries should be packed with your plugin during compilation and final .jar file will contain them. In IDEA, you have to create artifact configuration before compiling into .jar.
[image]

Then choose extract.

[image]

Then remove your bukkit entry from there (because we do not want to pack whole bukkit sources into our plugin) and you should see your API .jar file there. Then click Apply / OK.

[image]

Now when you build (compile) your plugin with `Build artifacts`, your API .jar will be compiled as well and packed into your plugin JAR file which will generate in `out\artifacts`

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your detailled answer! I have set everything like you've shown me but my API does not appear in the list (the last image). I added it manually via the little plus button and built my plugin and it still does not work for me.. :( It continues to throw the "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: tikzapi.TikZAPI" Error. Or was it wrong to add the API with the plus button?

Comment: Have you added your API JAR file into libraries in Project structure? You can check if generated plugin file has packed your API in zip/rar viewer. Since all .jar files are just packed sources, open your plugin .jar file with WinRAR for example and check there if there are also compiled .class files from your API. Or you can try solution mentioned below to make your API as individual plugin.

Comment: Yes, when I created my project I went to 'Project Structure' > 'Libraries' and added the spigotlib.jar and my TikZAPI.jar. From that point onwards, I went to 'Artifacts' > '+' > 'Jar' > 'From modules with dependencies' > checked 'extract to the target JAR' and clicked on 'OK'. In the output-layout section there is only my testplugin.jar and a subfolder with a little cyan square. The folder is called ''Testplugin' compile output'. When I open it with 7Zip, there is no API inside of it, I looked trough every folder in the jar, nothing... I really dont know what I am doing wrong...

Answer (score 0):

The best way here is to make the API as a plugin and load the dependency in the `plugin.yml`. That way, it is very easy to access it via any other plugin and there is no update compatibility issues if you use the API in different plugins. It is the norme with API in MC Server to create a plugin that acts as an API.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but is there a way to load the API without making it to a bukkit plugin? I further want to load the JavaMail API which is not by me so therefore I cant make that to an API.

Comment: With maven, you can compile your plugin with dependencies. You might to take a look at that on Google. That's how I would approach that problem.